# How to Auto Sort Multiple Sheets Using VBA in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to sort multiple sheets in excel using a Macro or VBA in excel. In addition I want a drop down menu to trigger the search. anyone know how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming you have a basic understanding of macros and subs....

- Add the Develeper Tab:https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-the-Developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45
- Open Visual Basic
- Insert a combo box on your excel document anywhere you want
- Title your sub or function ***comboboxname*_change**

Your sub will run whenever an option is selected.